# Is it correct to say "this book has immensely influenced my knowledge" (or my learning)

Tags: expressions

I want to express that a given book was very enlightening and influenced my learning  (positively) during the last year. This book really helped me to understand other related literature.

**Edit:**

In the context where I will use this, I need to be formal and concise. 
For clarification purpose, I will specify two questions for this thread

1) What is the correct one "influenced my knowledge" vs "influenced my learning"

2) Can you give me some alternatives for "This book has immensely influenced my knowledge/learning"

Comment: Knowledge is more like a collection of information. It is either in your head or it isn't. So "influence" isn't a good word to use with it.  You can influence what you decide to study ("influenced my learning" if that's what you mean by "learning"), or influence your thinking or opinion, which is what you do with the information or learning after it is in your head.  Sometimes "learning" is used more generally to include the "debate" associated with the information, but that is then part of what you acquire.  So "influence" doesn't apply well to directing your thinking if used with "learning".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about: This book or/ *title* by author, was very enlightening and influenced my learning positively during the last year. This book really helped me to understand other related literature.

You said it very clearly.

On edit --

*Title* by Author increased my understanding of the subject and was extremely enlightening.

Comment: ok, thank you. but this will be very long for the context where I need this. I have to shorten this up, so I asked for your help. another question stated is whether we say influenced my knowledge vs my learning.

Comment: @AymaneFihadi Maybe you should make the point that you need to be concise and you'll get answers you can use. I'll try editing, too.

Comment: Good answer, but I think _extremely_ might be a bit too strong here; _very_ might work better.

Comment: I didn't remark your update. I will use this one and Change extremely by very. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this sentence. I will use it and accept it if there is no other answer. Please let me know if it isn't correct, or you have a better one.

This book has been enlightening me during the last year and helped me to understand other related literature.